# AngularJS - event listener fired twice

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution for my problem:
I am new to AngularJS and I am using **Ionic with Firebase** to create an app. I want to block views from **unauthenticated** users. So when the user clicks on a view without authentication the **Login modal** should popup and redirect the view to home.

The code is like this:

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicModal', $state,...,
function($scope, $ionicModal, $state,...) {

// Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalLogin = modal;
  });

// Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    if(!$scope.modalLogin.isShown()){
      $scope.modalLogin.show();
    }  
  };

/*** Verify Authentication - This is the problematic part... ***/
  $scope.$on("$stateChangeStart", 
     function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        var auth = firebase.auth();

    if (toState.views.menuContent.authenticate && auth.currentUser === null){
      event.preventDefault();
      // User isn’t authenticated
      if(fromState.name != "app.home"){
        $state.go("app.home");
      }
      if(!$scope.modalLogin.isShown()){
        $scope.login();
      }      
    }
    else{
      return;
    }
  });


}]);
```

The thing is that no matter what I do the `$scope.$on("$stateChangeStart",)` callback function will fire twice. I checked for doubled controller declarations, I removed the `$scope.login()` function and even if the event listener is empty it is fired twice:

```
//Verify Authentication
      $scope.$on("$stateChangeStart", 
         function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            console.log('This fires twice...');   
         }
```

Any thoughts? I new to angularJS so maybe it's very simple solution, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your use case, where you want to block unauthenticated user, you are better off using AngularFire, the library has features relevant to your requirements,

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers

Comment: @srijanshukla Thanks for your comment. Actually, my first idea (and I think is the right way to do it) was doing exactly like this with a `.run` on app module using $rootScope. However, all my functions are related to $scope inside the controller(as you can see above) and I don't know how to use them from $rootScope. I am beginner in angularJS and it's all new to me. I followed a tutorial and it uses $scope inside the controller to call the authentication service, modal Login, logout etc... So when running with $rootScope I couldn't manage to trigger the modal when the user changes routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me in the past and the issue was because angular was being loaded twice. I had included the angular script, and ionic was including the angular script.

Removing our own angular script and letting ionic deal with it was the solution for me

Comment: Thanks man! It worked like a charm. I spent a few hours on this. The problem was that I was using angular-bind-html-compile and probably it is calling angular twice. Before I had called angularJS twice but somehow I always got a warning in the console, so I didn't bother much about it. Thanks again!